# How to disable string conversion in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a encrypted string which would be passed from the server side, now I want to test to convert it into readable language by some conventional decoding method.

but I found I totally cannot use the string:
[image]

The error shows: `invalid escape sequence in literal`.

There exists some conversions in swift string like `"\(variable)"` or `"\b"`.

Is there a way for me to use pure String?

For example. in python, I can declare `a = """content"""` to represent pure String

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the backslash (`\`), just before the character the up-arrow is pointing to in the error message. In a literal, this needs to be represented by a double backslash (`\\`).

This issue won't arise once you're no longer testing and you're doing this all with actual values; it's a feature only of literal strings.

Answer (score 0):

I recently fount a quick solution:

Use `' content '` instead of `" content "`, then Xcode would give you a warning.

[image]

Press Fix-it, Xcode would automatically add `\` at right places to avoid literal convention.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you save the string in a file in you app and read it from there, to avoid having to modify the string (it's a rather ugly string and you will have to escape a bunch of stuff).

You can use `NSBundle.pathForResource` and `NSString.initWithContentsOfFile` to get the string into memory from the file.